# Overloading using dynamic and inheritance

Tags: c#, dynamic, overloading, dispatch

I'm having an issue where I need dynamic dispatch (or at least that's what I think it should be called) with an inheritance structure. More specifically, I would like to use dynamic dispatch so I can add more specific overloads in inherited classes. I haven't been able to find anyone with quite the same problem as mine (things I find always talk about **overrides** in inherited classes, I need dynamic **overloading**). The strongly simplified situation is as follows:

```
class A
{
    private void DoSpecificStuff(object a);
    private void DoSpecificStuff(SomeClass a);
}

class B<T> : A
{
    private void DoSpecificStuff(OtherClass<T> a);
}
```

Then **inside A**, I have some function that consumes fields of some class using reflection. It goes like this:

```
public void Consume(JetAnotherClass a)
{
    // Fetch all fieldinfo's from a and for each fieldinfo, do this:
    foreach(FieldInfo info in a's fieldinfo's...)
            DoSpecificStuff((dynamic)fieldInfo.GetValue(a))
}
```

The calling site works as follows:

```
B b = new B();
b.Consume(new JetAnotherClass());
```

Now, every time the **fieldInfo.GetValue(a)** finds an instance of **SomeClass**, the desired overloaded function is being called with **SomeClass** as formal parameter. But when an instance of **OtherClass<>T>** is returned, it is **DoSpecificStuff(object a)** that gets called instead of **DoSpecificStuff(OtherClass<>T> a)**.

Why does my dynamic dispatch work perfectly within one class, but breaks when another class offers more overloads that should be dynamically dispatched on? Doesn't the dynamic dispatch start by looking inside the top-most instance, which is of type **B**?

PS: replacing private by (virtual) protected or anything like that doesn't help. In fact, it's way weirder that using private does work for the overloads inside **A**, since we're calling DoSpecificStuff with an implicit this parameter of type **B**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing to separate mechanisms:

- Polymorphism - or the ability to *runtime* call a function in a sub class, even though the reference is of base class type.
- Overload resolution that (normally, without `dynamic`) is a compile time resolution of the most specific matching function.

When you are using `dynamic` to defer the overload resolution to runtime you are still doing an overload resolution. The `Consume` method is in `A` so it will only look in `A` and have no idea of that `B` even exists.

To get the behaviour you want, I think that you should make a separate *virtual*  method for calling `DoSpecificStuff` that contains the `dynamic` magic. Then repeat that functionality in class `B`. That way an instance of `B` will use the method in `B` and find the right candidates when doing the overload resolution.

Comment: So even though the compiler will wait to resolve the overload until run-time because of the dynamic keyword, it does somehow remember that it should only be looking inside A?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because the method is defined in `A` and the overload resolution is separate from polymorphism and `virtual/override` methods.